# How to make this text grow when an image is hovered over?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want `.thumb_text` to grow when `li.thumb_list` `<img>` is hovered over. Currently, I can only get it to scale when I hover over the text, but not the `<img>`.

Also, for some reason the text is boldening no matter what weight or font family I give it.

```css
li.thumb_list img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

li.thumb_list:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

h1.thumb_text {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

h1.thumb_text:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.photo_thumbnails {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 235px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

li.thumb_list {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h1.thumb_text {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 999;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'anonymous pro', monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail_container">

  <div class="photo_thumbnails">

    <ul>

      <li class="thumb_list">
        <a href="http://scottnorris.co.uk/photos/uk.html"><img src="Photos/Thumbnails/UK.jpg" width="300" height="225">
          <h1 class="thumb_text">uk landscapes</h1>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="thumb_list">
        <a href="http://scottnorris.co.uk/photos/asia.html"><img src="Photos/Thumbnails/Asia.jpg" width="300" height="225">
          <h1 class="thumb_text">asian landscapes</h1>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="thumb_list">
        <a href="http://scottnorris.co.uk/photos/forgotten.html"><img src="Photos/Thumbnails/Lost.jpg" width="300" height="225">
          <h1 class="thumb_text">lost &amp; forgotten</h1>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="thumb_list">
        <a href="http://scottnorris.co.uk/photos/in-nature.html"><img src="Photos/Thumbnails/In_Nature.jpg" width="300" height="225">
          <h1 class="thumb_text">in nature</h1>
        </a>
        <li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the text to increase while hovering img you can use the CSS sibling selector like this:

```
.thumb_list img:hover + .thump_text{
font-size:50px;
}
```

Note that if you Hover the text with only this CSS it will decrease again, given that you've only chosen the Hover effect for the img.

To get around this you have (at least) two choices: set the Hover effect to the container instead (no need for sibling selector then) or add `pointer-events: none` to the `.thump_text`

With regard to your font being only bold, I guess it could be because you only have one font-weight available with your custom font. Usually you have to provide the browser with different files for each weight of font. On the other hand though, the browser usually tries to create its own weight, when either of the extremes is applied (100 or bold/700). This is just a guess though, but could be a possible reason.

Comment: Amazing - thank you. Hover works! 

Re the bold text. I'm using google fonts:

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

I've tried quite a few fonts now, with similar results. The weirdest thing is when I use the hover over the text it appears to be rendering back and forth between regular and bold for a few seconds before settling on bold. Very peculiar.

Comment: You're welcome. With regard to the font, have you checked that your havent specified a `font-weight: bold` or `font-weight: 700` somewhere in your CSS? And maybe try to set the font-weight to the same weight which you have downloaded (seems to be only 400 from you link). Lastly, please select the right answer og you fine it fulfilling :)

Comment: I just made a little test with your provided HTML and css, and I believe that what you are experiencing with the text is simply, that the browser can't perfectly translate the increased size to every pixel in the transition, making the text seem "wiggly" and at some points thinner - and in the end returning to it's initial weight. However, given that the text is now larger it seems slightly thicker/bolder than before. You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jw1y219c/